# How can I send emails so that replies don't get threaded as a single conversation?

Tags: email, gmail, bulk-email

I have a service sending out automated emails via Amazon SES with some questions to answer when people sign up, and currently all replies are being grouped into a single conversation in Google Inbox. Is there some way I can tell Google that these are separate conversations?

Comment: I'm not sure about Google Inbox, but with Gmail and most other email clients that group emails into conversations, varying the subject usually breaks the conversation.

Comment: Hmm, adding their name to the subject might be enough. That's a good point, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean this post for webapps.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I looked at that, but the solution to this would involve changing my automated emailer rather than changing settings in Inbox. I felt it fit here better.

Comment: Are these emails related to your website?   If not, this is not the appropriate place to ask.   http://serverfault.com/ might be more appropriate.

Comment: It's not really a technical question though. It seemed to me that what content or meta information an email should have to distinguish itself as a separate thread was a webmaster question.

Comment: Given I've been asked if this belongs better in webapps or serverfault, this seems like a happy halfway between the two.

Comment: You wrote it 'currently' happend - so it worked before? What did you change?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you as an answer the obvious one that applies for all e-mails from/to same sender/receiver that you do not want to be displayed as a thread (conversation) and you want each one of them to be displayed individually (in case you have not already set it up):

Open Gmail page > Click at the Gear icon > Settings > Conversation View > Set it to "Off"

Answer (score 0):

I just got an programmatically answer:

I guess [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421966/can-i-add-custom-message-id-and-in-reply-to-header-using-phpmailer) will help you.

Each eMail has in its header an id. So answers always belong to an id which can be found in eMails header.

So you have to send mails with different ids in their headers.